# how to make a webview fragment i can inflate for multiple diff webpages

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, android-inflate

i have a web-View layout. and i want to open it using a on item click and a list view. the list view has various web pages. also the list view is in its own activity called downloads. i want to be able to inflate the view but depending on position of on item click i would like a different web page to open thanks guys and i hope i explained my self properly

i have tried this on my on item click after Switch(position) in the case statement.

```
  LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)     
  this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 li.inflate(R.layout.webviewlayout, null);

 DownloadWebNav.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 DownloadWebNav.loadUrl(LilliPutSdCardUrl);
```

Comment: Bind your data with your list and get value from the adapter click.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create one common fragment which will open on itemclick of listview

After this open that fragment on itemclick of listview make sure when you replace the fragment you have to pass one string that contains url for load into webview
with setArguments() and in otherside in fragment you have to getArguments() so you will receive link for load into webview.

in fragment onResume() you have to get link and proceed to load in webview

Following is just example as refrance

```
newsLs.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TrialNewsFragment mFragment = new TrialNewsFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Data mNewsData = (Data) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (MainFragmentActivity.sDefSystemLanguage.equalsIgnoreCase("ar")) {
                    bundle.putString("news_desc", mNewsData.tDesc_ar);
                    bundle.putString("news_title", mNewsData.vTitle_ar);
                } else {

                    bundle.putString("news_desc", mNewsData.tDesc_en);
                    bundle.putString("news_title", mNewsData.vTitle_en);

                }
                bundle.putString("news_start", mNewsData.tCreateDate);
                bundle.putString("news_img", mNewsData.vLogo.original);
                mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity()).displayFragmentWithArg(mFragment);
            }
        });
```

One sample method which will replace fragment.

```
public void displayFragmentWithArg(Fragment mFragment) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.addToBackStack("back");
    transaction.replace(R.id.act_login_main_lContainer, mFragment).commit();
}
```

And in TrailnewsFragment onResume()

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null && args.containsKey("news_desc") && !args.equals(""))
        tvNewsDesc.setText(args.getString("news_desc"));
    if (args != null && args.containsKey("news_start") && !args.equals(""))
        tvNewsStartDate.setText(UtilMethods.getFormatedDate(args.getString("news_start"), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", "dd MMM,yyyy"));
    if (args != null && args.containsKey("news_title") && !args.equals(""))
        tvNewsHeading.setText(args.getString("news_title"));
    if (args != null && args.containsKey("news_img") && !args.equals("")) {
        if (args.getString("news_img") != null && !args.getString("news_img").equals(""))
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(args.getString("news_img")).placeholder(R.drawable.defaultimage).into(ivNewsImage);
    }
```

Comment: is there any examples of this please it confusing